# Unable to capture request and response values into csv by using sample variables

Tags: csv, jmeter

Could some one please advise me where am i doing wrong.

When i tried to capture request and response values into csv using sample variables  by adding in the next line to user.properties file: sample_variables=request,response

it's throwing null in the request and response columns in the csv file.

Is there is any another work around to achieve this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks,
Rajani

[image]

Comment: And do you have **variables** called "request" and "response"? How are they defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the below steps to capture the request URL and response. Alternatively, you can extract the request/response using Bean Shell sampler.

1. Open **JMeter.Properties** and configure the sample variables. Restart JMeter.

[image: JMeter.Properties]

2. In your test plan, create **two Regular Expression Extractors** for your HTTP request, one is to capture '**request**' and another is to capture the '**response**'. Use (?s)(^.*) regular expression to extract everything.

To capture the **request**, configure as shown below. If you want to capture the request headers, select **Request Headers** radio button.

[image: Request]

To capture the **response**, configure as shown below.

[image: Response]

3. In the **Aggregate report**, make sure you checked the options as shown below and provide a name in Filename e.g. google.csv.

[image: Report]

4. Here is my JMeter test plan for Google.com

[image: Test Plan]

5. Here is the expected output. Check in the JMETER_HOME\bin\google.csv.

[image: Output]

Comment: I am glad. But executing tests by logging requests and response is not a good practice.

Comment: yes I agree with you, i told this to my boss it's up to him. One qucik question.My application is SOAP based and  request and response are huge due to this  it's hard to map  with the associated SamplerLabel ,ThreadName and rest of the fields labels .  I have tried saving csv and save as xls to fit request and response in their receptive columns . How can i achieve this i mean request and response data fit in columns.I have attached the screenshots to the original post.Please advise me!

Comment: By the I have used FlexibleFileWriter. In either ways meaning FFW,SamplerVaraibles mapping is jigjack. See the screenshot to the original post Please advise me!

Comment: In JMeter.Properties, please set below property.

view.results.tree.max_size=0

Comment: I tried # Set to 0 to disable the size check and display the whole response
#view.results.tree.max_size=10485760
view.results.tree.max_size=0  as well as  view.results.tree.max_size=0-  both didn't work. Please advise!