# How do I save JMeter variables created at runtime? (specifically a snippet of JSON to xml)

Tags: java, json, jmeter, automated-tests

I'm using JMeter 3.1 to run a http-endpoint test & I need to extract a very small portion of the return JSON I receive.

I'm using the JSON Extractor postprocessor element & JSONPath expressions to find my value. [This post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/25424/how-to-use-http-request-json-extractorusing-jmeter-variable-in-jmeter-with-res) does a *really* good job of explaining how to assign the value I'm looking for to a runtime variable.

However it stops short of explaining how to save said variable to an output file. I can check to make sure that I've pulled the data using an assertion rule; I can even save the true/false value of that check. Saving the variable itself however, seems less straightforward.

I have 3 ideas and am likely going to spend the next few hours exploring them & checking this thread. So,

### Will any of these work?:

- Figure out what "Sub Results" means to JMeter and see if I can get my JSON snippet there.
- Make another sampler that (somehow) just reads & returns a variable I pass it at runtime, whenever a thread executes.
- Figure out if "Assertion Results" is capable of saving anything other than "TRUE" or "FALSE."
- While we're at it, I'm going to see what these friggin mean'

[image: Here's an image!]

Comment: Refer this link to save the variable to output file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43012958/unable-to-capture-request-and-response-values-into-csv-by-using-sample-variables/43020106#43020106

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the next lines to *user.properties* file (located in "bin" folder of JMeter installation)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
sample_variables=YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME_HERE
```

Next time you run your test you will see your variable value appended to .jtl results file.

Reference material:

- [Sample Variables Property](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thissssss answer is terrific and a very precise distillation of what I just spent my sunday on. Thank you sir. gd it I wish you were here 4 hours ago but thank you(>_<).